# Continuing video capture even after exiting from the current frame- Two different frames from a single webcam with different functions

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, video-capture, opencv3.0

Basically what I did was capture the video using cv2.videocapture in 'frame2' and extracted data from it and then closed the current video capture session using cap.release and then wanted to start a new video capture and use the previously extracted data from the first video capture .But it keeps lagging on the second video capture while pressing 'q'.
Like it should be capturing video after the first cap release as smoothly as it does in a normal video capture of a single session
Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
x=0
while(x==0):
    while(1):
        #some functions 
        _,frame2 = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('frame2',frame2)

        k=cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        if k == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyWindow('frame2')
            x=1
            break
cap.release()
cap2=cv2.VideoCapture(0)                
while(1):
    _,frame = cap2.read()
    #again some functions
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    j=cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    if j == ord('y'):
    break                    



cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Would you mind to rephrase? Too confusing...

Comment: done the rephrasing :D